# I want to create like this table pagination from NgPrime

Tags: angular, sass, frontend

I want to create like this table pagination from Angular NgPrime. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: If you want to play with making such code (without using any of the actual pagination packages), take a look at the paginator I made for such purpose: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mmpaginator there's a stackblitz demo with all the code needed for it to function, so you can explore it.